# It is possible to avoid rewriting many times the same callback?

Tags: java, gwt, callback, duplicates

I need to call a service passing always the same callback "AsyncCallbackAdapter"

```
    auditingServicesRpc.tracePrivacy(requestDesc, ip, new AsyncCallbackAdapter<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Integer arg0) {}

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
            super.onFailure(caught);

        }
    });
```

This is the AsyncCallbackAdapter that implements AsyncCallback from GWT

```
    import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.AsyncCallback;
    public abstract class AsyncCallbackAdapter<T> implements AsyncCallback<T> {
        private Boolean caughtException = false;

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
            //log
            GWT.log(caught.getMessage());

            //invalid session handling
            if (caught instanceof InvocationException) {
        ...
            //other common handling
        }

        private void sessionExpired() {
            ...
        }

        public Boolean getCaughtException() {
            return caughtException;
        }

        public AsyncCallbackAdapter() {

        }
    }
```

I would like create a method like this in abstrast superclass AsyncCallbackAdapter

```
public static AsyncCallbackAdapter<T> getInstance(){

    return new AsyncCallbackAdapter<T>(){
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(T result) {
        };

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
            super.onFailure(caught);

        }
    };
}
```

but I can't because I "Cannot make a static reference to the no-static type T".

Do you have any idea!?!?
Thank you

---

@user902383
Thank you, this method remove all errors, but how can I use this method? I need use Integer for T. 
Using this:

```
    AsyncCallbackAdapter.getInstance()
```

Eclipse tell me:
"- The method tracePrivacy(String, String, AsyncCallback) in the type IAuditingServiceRpcAsync is not applicable for the arguments (String, String, AsyncCallbackAdapter)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try   `public static <T> AsyncCallbackAdapter<T> getInstance(){ ...}` this should fix your problem

Comment: Thank you, this method remove all errors, but how can I use this method? I need use Integer for T. Using this:

    AsyncCallbackAdapter.getInstance()

Eclipse tell me: "- The method tracePrivacy(String, String, AsyncCallback) in the type IAuditingServiceRpcAsync is not applicable for the arguments (String, String, AsyncCallbackAdapter)"

Comment: `AsyncCallbackAdapter.<Integer>getInstance()`